# Echo variable in more files

Tags: php

In `first.php` i have `$name = "Josh"`. How to `echo $name` in `secound.php`. Both are in same folder.

In `first.php`

```
$name = "Josh";
```

In `secound.php`

```
echo $name;
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: name in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Folder\secound.php on line 2

Edit

```
include 'first.php';

echo $name;
```

Comment: The PHP interpreter is top-bottom, so if you don't have $name instantiated before the call, will never work. Include the first script before your call of $name and will be good.

Comment: i did it. but i have some html code and it's include that html

Comment: So separate the html code from the logic of the application with functions and get the name value after that as you wish. If you put the content of both php here will help A LOT.

Answer (score 1):

To access the data in the second file, you'll need to include it.

At the top of your secound.php script, add this code:

```
include 'first.php';
```

You could also use require, like this:

```
require 'first.php';
```

The difference between the two can be found in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/require):

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also
>   produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will
>   halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which
>   allows the script to continue.

Comment: same problem, again.

Comment: include or require needs to go before the echo in second.php

Comment: @Lazar, could you update your question to show us where you have added the include/require statement?